# On a horizontally setup 20m delta loop I am looking to determine the calculations for the proper length of a feed wire

Tags: antenna, antenna-theory, hf, feed-line, loop-antenna

Base of loop will be about 6 feet above ground. RG-8 or 213 will be used for the feed wire.  Ugly balun as well.

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Comment: Are you feeding it at a corner, or in the center of one leg? Kindly edit your question with this info, so someone can (hopefully) model it for you and determine the feedpoint impedance.

Comment: @MikeWaters [this page](https://palomar-engineers.com/tech-support/tech-topics/loop-antennas) says that the feed-point impedance of a full-wave loop is about 100 Ω.

Comment: Is your loop parallel with the ground?

Answer (score 1):

Best solution is with an antenna tuner for impedance matching. Cheap-try is quarter lambda 70 Ohm cable (to convert 100 Ohm to nearby 50 Ohm) AND common-mode isolator. I assume your loop is NOT parallel to the ground, since it makes no sense at 14 MHz to have your radiation straight upward. PA0FSB